# Is a Finite Integration Interval, for Dirac Delta Functionals, Allowed?

Tags: measure-theory, dirac-delta

I was trained in physics and the way that I learned about Delta functionals was as the limit of a sequence of integrals that contain a "Delta sequence" and a nice function, f. That is,

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta_n(x'-x) f(x') dx' = f(x)$

The resulting functional was written as

$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x'-x) f(x') dx' = f(x)$

where the Delta function, $\delta(x'-x)$, is a "generalized function".

I understand it is also possible to define Delta functions and Delta functionals in terms of measures.

I am wondering, is it rigorously acceptable to write the Delta functional as

$\int_{x-a}^{x+b} \delta(x'-x) f(x') dx' = f(x)$

for $a$ and $b$ being some positive numbers? I know when the Delta function is defined as a limit of a sequence of integrals, they always integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Maybe that is not necessary, or not necessary when the Delta functional is defined in terms of measures? If the answer is that it is OK to specify the Delta functional over a finite interval, then what is the definition/derivation of the Delta function or Delta functional that would allow that?

I suppose that if $f(x) = 0$ for $x \notin [x-a,x+b] $, then it should be OK. How about if that is not the case?

I have seen some people use a finite integration interval and was wondering if they were being too loose with their notation. Curious what the answer is from a mathematician's perspective.

Comment: No problem with that. An integral over an interval not containing $x'=x$ is zero.

Comment: As long as $x$ is inside the integration interval, it's OK, since $\delta (x'-x) =0$ outside.

Comment: Thanks, Yves and Herb. But, if we define the functional as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta_n(x'-x) f(x') dx' = f(x)$, where  $ \delta_n$ is a sequence of "regular functions", then surely it would matter if we change the integration interval to being finite? Is it the measure theory-based definition that makes the finite integration interval OK?

Comment: Restricting the range of integration to an interval $J$ is equivalent to replacing $f$ by $f\mathbf{1}_{J}$, where $$\mathbf{1}_{J}(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in J \\ 0, & x \notin J \end{cases} $$ is the indicator function for $J$. This allows us to focus only on the integration on all of $\mathbb{R}$ with test functions $f$ allowed to behave wilder.

Comment: And although you can allow any suitable Borel measurable function $f$ when defining $\int f(x) \delta(dx)$, it need not (and in general do not) coincide with the limit of $\int f(x) \delta_n(x) \, dx$ unless $f$ is continuous at $0$. This failure persists even if you restrict $f$ to only have jump discontinuities.

Comment: Thank you Sangchul. But if my $f$ is physically not $0$ outside of finite $J$, then making the range of integration for the functional be $J$ would be incorrect, since a finite interval of integration is equivalent to $f$ having support only in $J$?